# Definition of inner product required for linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question is about some general, non-specific vector space.

The well-known definition of linear independence for vectors $\vec v_1, \vec v_1,...,\vec v_n$ is that the equation
 $$a_1\vec v_1+a_2\vec v_2+\cdots+a_n\vec v_n= \vec 0$$
is only satisfied by $a_m=0$  for all $m$.

From this definition, it seems to me that the concept of linear independence be defined without first defining the inner product. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, no inner product is required to talk about linear independence.  Linear independence works on vector spaces over arbitrary fields, with no inner product in sight.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Linear independence does not involve the definition of inner products.

Comment: And importantly -- linear independence "works" for any vector space, and *many* of them do not have any notion of inner product.